# How to update the package explorer manually (Preferences)

Tags: eclipse, rcp, workbench

I have added a custom LabelDecorator to an Eclipse 3.6, which replaces the cryptic usernames added by the SVN Team Text Decorations. The SVN Team Decorator allows you to add an author tag. What I did was adding another Decorator replacing these author strings (which are company specific shortnames with numbers) with the actual name of the user.

While SVN Team Text Decorations extends the Package Explorer with:

```
... com.company.package · XY9723 · [30.02.11 19:11]
```

I replace that by

```
... com.company.package · Neil Diamond · [30.02.11 19:11]
```

Now, to complete the mission, I added a preference page, where users are able to specify the attributes (name, forename, birthdate, company name, telephone, etc.), which should be used as replacement. I'd like to update the package explorer (or whereever svn team decorates ressources) with the newly selected attributes whenever "Apply" or "Ok" is pressed. 
At the moment the ressources are only updated after you have pressed "Apply" or "Ok" **and** manually collapse/expand one of the ressource in the explorer.

Is there some event I could fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the IDecorationManager interface:

```
IWorkbench workbench = ...;
IDecoratorManager manager = workbench.getDecoratorManager();
```

**inside of the prefernce pages LabelProvider:**

```
ILabelDecorator decorator = manager.getLabelDecorator("com.plugin.mydecorator");
if(decorator != null){ // decorator is enabled
    LabelProviderChangedEvent event = new LabelProviderChangedEvent(demoDecorator);
    // update specific resources
    fireLabelEvent(event, arrayOfResourceToUpdate);

    // or update all resources
    fireLabelEvent(event);
}
```

-> see [Understanding Decorators](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Decorators/decorators.html#Re-Decorate)

**without a LabelProvider**

```
manager.update("com.plugin.mydecorator");
```

-> see [DecoratorManager.java](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/org/eclipse/ui/internal/decorators/DecoratorManager.java.html)

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: You propose I should trigger a selection event on all affected ressources in the package explorer or any other open view which uses text decorations from the svn plug-in?

Comment: sorry.. I kind of missed the point of your question before and therefore updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you **very** much. I haven't looked closely enough to the "Understand Decorators" article, which clearly says how to do it. Or -at least- what the author did to solve this issue. He actually stores all successfully decorated ressources and uses those collections (`arrayOfResourceToUpdate`) to initialize the LabelChanged-Event, which will then be fired from the within the decorator itself, after checking whether its enabled or not. Great, eldn. Thanks again.

Comment: I personally would rather prefer a solution without the ressource storage aspect, but I guess if the article of ibm uses this techique its state of the art.